# How to capture prompts in stdout/stderr?

Tags: python, unix, haskell, pipe, tee

I'm trying to record a user's terminal session in a log file; fairly simply, I made a Python wrapper for `ghci` (interactive Haskell) that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

cmd = 'ghci 2>&1 | tee hs.log'
os.system(cmd)
```

However, this only captures what is printed *back* to the user, and not the prompts/what the user has typed in. So if the session looks like:

```
$ ghci 2>$1 | tee hs.log
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 1+2
3
Prelude> 3+4
7
Prelude>
```

`hs.log` only has:

```
$ cat hs.log
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
3
7
```

How do you capture both the output and the input during an interactive terminal session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) command to capture both input and output.

```
cmd = 'script hs.log ghci'
```

Note that this captures all the raw input and output from the terminal. You'll see all the user's editing, and if the program is full-screen you'll see all its escape sequences to move the cursor around. See the linked documentation for full details.

Comment: Note that `script` logs non-canonical (raw) user input, not just stdin/out/err.  For example, if the user makes a mistake and presses backspace then everything, including the backspace character, is recorded.

Comment: Right, that's a bit annoying to parse. Is there another way to do this without `script`? I just need each line output at the terminal every newline or whatever.

Comment: Not without writing your own program that sits in between the user and the application, so it reads the user input and saves it before piping it to the application. I don't know of anything simple that does this.